# What is the meaning of <%= var_name %> in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm reading shell script from [here](https://github.com/cescoffier/puppet-play/blob/master/templates/play-upstart.erb) and there are variables like

```
env PROJ_HOME=<%= path %>
```

this means that I must change this with a string which is the path isn't it? Sorry for this question but for automatize this I need to pass this as variables not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `puppet` template for the shell script, what use [`erb`](http://www.rrn.dk/rubys-erb-templating-system) template engine.
In [`erb`](http://www.rrn.dk/rubys-erb-templating-system).

```
<% "ERB will evaluate this!" %>
<%= "ERB will evaluate and output this!" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an ERB file, not a shell script. ERB is a means of writing dynamic templates, and the `<%= path %>` structure you've noticed is to interpolate a value into the template.

Essentially, `<%= path %>` will be replaced by a value such as `/home/user/somedir`